# Controlling width of annotated heatplots in plotly subplots

Tags: python, plotly, width, heatmap, subplot

I've been really struggling with a mulitplot of annotated heatmaps. I have the multiplot now, the code below should be reproducible, but I can't control the width of each individual plot.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame({'strats': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'de', 'de'],
                 'z': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                 'title': ['this day will never end ever more texts', 'short', 'short', 
                           'very long', 'very very long', 
                           'very very very very very long',
                          'short', 'short']})
strats = pd.unique(df['strats'])
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=len(strats), 
                    horizontal_spacing=0.015,
                   column_widths=[3]*len(strats))
heatmaps = []
annotations = []
for i in range(len(strats)):
    r_strat = df[df['strats'] == strats[i]]
    heatmaps.append(ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
        x=[strats[i]], 
        z=[[r] for r in r_strat['z']],
        annotation_text=[[r] for r in r_strat['title']],
        hoverinfo='text',
        colorscale='algae')
    )
    fig.add_trace(heatmaps[i].data[0], row=1, col=i+1)
    heatmaps[i].layout.width = 300 # this is not used
    annotations = heatmaps[i].layout.annotations
    for k in range(len(annotations)):
        annotations[k]['xref'] = f'x{i+1}'
        annotations[k]['yref'] = f'y{i+1}'
    for ano in annotations:
        fig.add_annotation(ano)
    
    if i == 1:
        fig.update_layout(yaxis2 = dict(visible=False, categoryorder='array'))
    elif i==2:
        fig.update_layout(yaxis3 = dict(visible=False, categoryorder='array'))
    elif i==3:
        fig.update_layout(yaxis4 = dict(visible=False, categoryorder='array'))
    elif i==4:
        fig.update_layout(yaxis5 = dict(visible=False, categoryorder='array'))
    else:
        fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(visible=False, categoryorder='array'))
        
fig.update_layout(title='Popularity Spectrum',
                 paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')
```

On my browser, this renders with the first plot thinner than the others.
[image]

Here the a subplot is thinner than the others. This isn't too bad, but for the real plot I'm plotting the output is unreadable.

I'd like all the plots to have the same thickness, or at least figure out how to control it. Does anyone know how this is done? I think it must be done within the heatmap portion of the code, as opposed to the subplot layout.

Comment: Can you present the current output? I am not sure of the point you are addressing. I ran your code and the annotations overhang partially, but the height and width are identical.

Comment: I'll add it to the original post

Comment: I tried to run your code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EtA7a7Jqhbnd8yFNAg7Jbay02KQW5_7W?usp=sharing). This is the output. Even in my environment, the text of the first annotation sticks out a bit more.

Comment: Interesting. I bet it is browser or environment specific. Still can't figure out what parameters affect this.

Comment: I will disable it now that you have confirmed the published link. By the way, my environment is firefox and jupyterlab latest.

Comment: This hasn't helped solve the problem at all though

Comment: If you can't solve the problem here, there is a [community](https://community.plotly.com/) hosted by PLOTLY itself, so one way is to ask there.